# how to test a class and her subclass

Tags: java, unit-testing, inheritance, subclass, code-duplication

If I have class A and a subclass B, is there a way to write a test case which will be able to check a function in both classes without code duplication in two separate classes ATest and BTest?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the generic tests in TestA using an instance of class A, which is created in the setup

Then extends TestA within TestB and use the instance of class B for the B-specific tests, making sure that you override the setup so this instance is passed to the tests in class TestA

All the unit test cases will be reused without duplication

Comment: Is there a way to do it with one class using parameter annotation or something like this?